# How can I abort NSStepper auto-repeating?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent

I have an auto-repeating `NSStepper` that I want to stop tracking when I receive a certain `NSNotification`.

One idea was to just send `[_stepper setAutorepeat: NO]` from the method that receives the notification.  That doesn't work.  I suppose that the stepper only checks the autorepeat flag when tracking starts.

Then I thought I could subclass `NSStepperCell`, and use an override of`-[NSCell continueTracking:at:inView:]` to abort tracking.  However, apparently that method does not get called when a stepper is auto-repeating without the mouse moving.

Do I need to completely rewrite `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:`?  I suppose then I'd have to handle highlighting parts of the stepper as the mouse moves in or out, and I don't see any public API to even find out which part is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting a mouse up event.  I subclassed `NSStepperCell` just as a convenient place to watch for the notification and post the event.

```
@interface AbortableStepperCell : NSStepperCell
{
    BOOL    _isTracking;
    BOOL    _isObserverInstalled;
}


@implementation AbortableStepperCell

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)startTrackingAt: (NSPoint) startPoint
    inView: (NSView *) controlView
{
    _isTracking = YES;

    if ( ! _isObserverInstalled )
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            addObserver: self
            selector: @selector(abortTracking:)
            name: @"AbortMouseTracking"
            object: nil];

        _isObserverInstalled = YES;
    }

    return [super startTrackingAt: startPoint inView: controlView];
}

- (void) abortTracking: (NSNotification*) note
{
    if (_isTracking)
    {
        NSWindow* myWindow = self.controlView.window;
        NSGraphicsContext* gc =
            [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithWindow: myWindow];

        NSEvent* upEvent = [NSEvent
            mouseEventWithType: NSLeftMouseUp
            location: NSZeroPoint
            modifierFlags: 0
            timestamp: 0.0
            windowNumber: myWindow.windowNumber
            context: gc
            eventNumber: 0
            clickCount: 1
            pressure: 0.0f ];

        if (upEvent)
        {
            [NSApp postEvent: upEvent atStart: YES];
        }
    }
}

- (void)stopTracking:(NSPoint)lastPoint
        at:(NSPoint)stopPoint
        inView:(NSView *)controlView
        mouseIsUp:(BOOL)flag
{
    _isTracking = NO;

    [super stopTracking: lastPoint
            at: stopPoint
            inView: controlView
            mouseIsUp: flag];
}

@end
```